# MySQL Array Associative Only (PHP/MySQL/ADODB/JSON)

Tags: php, mysql, json, associative-array, adodb

I'm using PHP+MySQL+ADODB to fetch an array from the database and then convert it to JSON. However, the object ends up with duplicate entries (associative and numeric).

How would I go about returning only the associative rows?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$rs  = $conn->execute($sql);
$result = $rs->getrows();
echo json_encode($result);
```

// OUTPUT

```
{
    "0": "18556",
    "VID": "18556",
    "1": "1",
    "UID": "1",
    "2": "Title of entry",
    "title": "Title of entry",
    "3": "0",
    "likes": "0",
    "4": "0",
    "dislikes": "0"
}
```

Comment: Did you define the getrows function?  If so, can you post that code?  I'm not finding 'getrows' in the php manual, and the solution probably lies there in creating an associative array, rather than what you're seeing.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm using ADODB, it's an ADODB function.

Comment: Documentation maybe? http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:adodb_fetch_mode or http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:setfetchmode

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need as I don't want to set it globally. http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:setfetchmode